# Why doesn't it wait for me to input string after I exit the loop using CTRL+D

Tags: c, loops, scanf, fgets, eof

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char c, char_array[100];
    int i = 0;
    printf("Enter characters (press CTRL+D to end):\n");
    while(fgets(char_array+i,sizeof(char_array)-i,stdin)) {
        i = i + strlen(char_array+i);
        if(char_array[i-1] == EOF)
            break;
    }
    char_array[i-1] = '\0';
    strtok(char_array,"\n");
    printf("\nEnter a string:\n");
    char string[100];
    fgets(string,sizeof(string),stdin);
    printf("\nCharacter Array: %s\n", char_array);
    printf("String: %s\n", string);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code and I have tried many different variations(simpler) but it always has the same problem... I enter the characters, press CTRL+D and it ends without waiting for me to input a string. please help

I tried everything I could but I just cant make it work and my friends cant too... I have and exam and I need this to be done in 3 days max so I need all the help I can get.

Comment: Because you ended the input stream. You could use an empty string to terminate the loop.

Comment: About `if(char_array[i-1] == EOF)` the `EOF` isn't an actual character from the input but a signal value. The loop ended because `fgets()` returned `NULL`, not because of finding an `EOF` in the string input.

Comment: Not sure about the consequences of typing enough to fill the array and then loop and ask `fgets()` to load into a buffer of 0 bytes... And, I'm not willing to give my `fgets()` the nervous breakdown this will probably cause...

Comment: how do i use an empty string to terminate the loop?

Comment: The length of an empty string is 0... And, `break;` will terminate the loop.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Pressing Control-D after entering some characters (not enter/return) does not end the input stream. It sends the characters to the program, after which another read will get more characters (once they are entered). (Pressing Control-D after an enter/return also does not end the input stream. It will cause `fgets` to return a null pointer, but you can clear the EOF and error indicators and keep going.)

Comment: Update the question with the exact details of what keys you press, what program behavior you observe, and what program behavior you want instead. Be specific about pressing A, B, C, Enter or Return, Control+D, and so on, and exactly when the program prints output during the pressing of keys.

Comment: @EricPostpischil so how do i fix this?

Comment: @petyr: Edit the question to provide the information as I described above.

Comment: `if(char_array[i-1] == EOF)` is incorrect. `EOF` is generally an `int` value that is returned from some routines like `getchar`. `fgets` does not put `EOF` into the buffer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil well its pretty simple, i press a character then i press enter, then i can do it as many times as i want, but once i press CTRL + D it doesnt wait for me to input a string, it just ends the whole program... i want it to ask me for chars, add it to an array using loop, and then i want it to ask me for a string

Comment: Normally, your `while` loop will not terminate until the user enters Control-D when there is no input in the buffer, which occurs at the start of a new line or immediately after Control-D was pressed. Once that happens, the EOF indicator for the stream is set, and another `fgets` will not be successful until you clear the EOF indicator. It is not clear how you want the program to behave, so you have to explain the behavior you want before somebody can tell you how to fix it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil could you rewrite the code so it works and send it to me somehow? it would really help me and id appreciate it a lot

Comment: @petyr: No. First, that is inappropriate to ask. Second, it is not possible to write a program that “works” without knowing what “works” means. Each program has some *specification*. That may be a formal document that says what it should do, but, even for a homework assignment, there is some statement about what the program is supposed to do. You have not stated what the program is supposed to do. Should it read input until `char_array` is full? Until return or enter is pressed? Until the first time `fgets` returns a null pointer? Something else? Then what?

Answer (score 0):

1. `fgets()` returns `NULL` when the stream is closed.  On Linux Ctrl-D will flush the terminal buffer if it's not empty (but `fgets()` will not return as it remains line buffered), and a 2nd Ctrl-D is required to trigger the EOF state of the stream.
2. You also want to terminate the loop if the array is full otherwise it's an infinite loop:

```
#define ARRAY_LEN 100

//...

    while(i < ARRAY_LEN - 1 && fgets(char_array + i, ARRAY_LEN - i,stdin)) {
```

3. `fgets()` will not emit `EOF` as part of the string being read, so this is simply incorrect, and as stdin is line buffered the last character is either `\n` or whatever if the last character was read if the buffer is full which could be `-1` or `0xff` (whatever char is signed or not but that's still wrong):

```
        if(char_array[i-1] == EOF)
            break;
```

4. The next line:

```
    char_array[i-1] = '\0';
```

strips the last character which is either `\n` or whatever we read last if the array is full (i.e. data loss).

5. As the input stream is in the `EOF` state the 2nd `fgets()` will return NULL.  You can clear that state with `clearerr(stdin)` before calling `fgets()` to get the 2nd string.  If the stream indeed ended, as in, `echo "hello world" | ./your_program`, the 2nd `fgets()` with return NULL again of course.

I suggest you use a blank line to signify end of input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAY_LEN 100

int main() {
    printf("Enter characters (empty line to end):\n");
    char char_array[ARRAY_LEN];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_LEN - 1; i += strlen(char_array)) {
        if(!fgets(char_array + i, ARRAY_LEN - i, stdin)) {
            printf("fgets() failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if(char_array[i] == '\n') {
            char_array[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    strtok(char_array, "\n");
    printf("Enter a string:\n");
    char string[ARRAY_LEN];
    char *rv = fgets(string,sizeof(string),stdin);
    printf("Character Array: %s\n", char_array);
    printf("String: %s\n", string);
}
```

and example session:

```
Enter characters (empty line to end):
hello
world

Enter a string:
friend
Character Array: hello
String: friend
```

Comment: EOF on _everyone’s_ system is `-1`, but the important point is that it is a bit-value _larger_ than the available range of valid input. A `char` may be signed or unsigned, but valid values returned from `getchar()` will always be 0..255 maximum (8 bits set), where `-1` is all bits set.

Comment: @Dúthomhas  Thanks.  I tweaked the answer re EOF and -1.  What defines EOF as -1?  I don't see it in the C standard other than 7.4 "nor representable as an unsigned char".  Right so user could theoretically enter whatever 0xff encodes and compare equal to EOF but I pointed out that will not happen.  We are not talking about getchar() but fgets(), i.e. chars.

Comment: @AllanWind, the stdio.h header file defines EOF as -1.  The standard (7.21.1) just specifies that it is a macro that expands to a value with `int` type that is negative.

Comment: @ChrisDodd *Your* stdio.h defines it as -1 ;-).

Comment: According to POSIX EOF can be any negative number. `-1` is just the easiest target for that and I don’t know of any system where it is not — but I’ve never had to care or verify, as the whole point is that the high bit(s) are set in the return value, whereas valid character input cannot have those bits set.

Answer (score 0):

With stdio streams, error/eof is *sticky* -- that is, once an error or eof condition has occurred, further operations on the `FILE *` will continue to return EOF or NULL (depending on the function), rather than trying to read or write anything further.

To reset the eof state on the `FILE *`, you need to call `clearerr(stdin)`.  Once you do that, you can read additional input from the terminal.